# CSS rule shows as empty in Firebug

Tags: css, firebug

The following rule has no content (is empty) when I view the styles in Firebug:

```
.holest-carousel-top-item 
{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF,-1px -1px 1px #9ACC67;border-radius: 85px;
}
```

The rule also isn't rendering in firefox.

I believe I read somewhere that firebug does not display styling that firefox won't render, but I don't know why firefox wouldn't render this rule. I checked the source in firefox and it shows there.

My only hint is that the link to the stylesheet containing this rule is in the body and not the header.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a spread radius as well: `1px 1px 1px 1px #FFF`. Any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of of Firefox you are using? In older versions of Firefox you have to define the vendor prefix `-moz` like this:

```
.holest-carousel-top-item 
{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF,-1px -1px 1px #9ACC67;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF,-1px -1px 1px #9ACC67;
    border-radius: 85px;
    -moz-border-radius: 85px;
}
```